# Angular. call function in directive from html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to make a directive. so that i can use it in my html page like the snippet below:

```
<testview></testview>
```

right now the only thing that is gonna do is render a link like

```
<a><span ng-onmousedown='onSelected(\"creame\",event)'>{{value}}</span></a>
```

And when i click on the span, i want the directive to change the $scope.value by calling the onSelected function. but i can't call this.

Full code sample

```
function testView() {

    $scope.value =
    {
        name: "dummy"
    }

    testHtml += "<a><span ng-onmousedown='onSelected(\"creame\",event)'  >" + $scope.value.name + "</span></a>";
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: 'true',
        template: testHtml,
    };
}
app.directive('testview', testView);

function onSelected(input)
{
    $scope.value.name = input;
}
```

does anyone know how I can do this?
thanks for your time

Comment: "_but i can't call this._" Why not? What happens if you call it just like any other regular function?

Comment: you have to add the function to $scope

Comment: @takendarkk nothing, no error's.

Comment: I think it is ng-mousedown

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function testView() {

testHtml += "<a><span ng-onmousedown='onSelected(\"creame\")'  >{{value.name }}</span></a>";
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: 'true',
        template: testHtml,
    };
}
app.directive('testview', testView);
app.controller('CampaignsOverviewController', Controller);

function Controller ($scope) {
  $scope.onSelected = onSelected;
  $scope.value =
       {
          name: "dummy"
       }
     function onSelected(input)
       {
         $scope.value.name = input;
        }

 }
```

Comment: im trying to keep the functions in the directive

Comment: inside directive object, add property `controller` and assign a string with value that you specified for controller name. I used `CampaignsOverviewController` in hurry, change it some more useful

Comment: you have to provide a controller to bind such methods

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to [compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) your template before the ngOnMouseDown directive can be executed.